# how to add condition in clock program Ex : hour>=0 and <=23

Tags: java

I have questions in my project code.

My project is

[image]

My questions in task 1 (2) and task 2 (1)

How to add the condition in my code?

My 2 classes are:

```
package date;

public class CTime {

int hour;
int minute;
int second;

public CTime(int h, int m, int s) {

    hour = h;
    minute = m;
    second = s;
}

public void setHour(int h) {
    hour = h;
}

public int getHour() {
    return hour;
}

public void setMinute(int m) {
    minute = m;
}

public int getMinute() {
    return minute;
}

public void setSecond(int s) {
    second = s;
}

public int getSecond() {
    return second;
}

public void tick() {
    second++;
    if (second > 59) {
        second = 0;
        minute++;
        if (minute > 59) {
            minute = 0;

            hour++;
        }
        if (hour > 23) {
            hour = 0;
        }

    }
}

public String toString() {
    String s = (hour > 9 ? hour : "0" + hour) + ":" + (minute > 9 ? minute : "0" + minute) + ":" + (second > 9 ? second : "0" + second);
    return s;
}

}
```

The second class:

```
package date;



public class CDateTime extends CTime {

int day;
int month;
int year;

public CDateTime(int ye, int mo, int d, int h, int m, int s) {
    super(h, m, s);
    year = ye;
    month = mo;
    day = d;

}

public void setYear(int ye) {
    year = ye;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setMonth(int mo) {
    month = mo;
}

public int getMonth() {
    return month;
}

public void setDay(int d) {
    day = d;
}

public int getDay() {
    return day;
}

public void tick() {
    second++;
    if (second > 59) {
        second = 0;
        minute++;
        if (minute > 59) {
            minute = 0;
            hour++;
        }

    }
    if (hour > 23) {
        hour = 0;
        day++;
        if (day > 30) {
            month++;
            day = 1;
            if (month > 12) {
                year++;
                month = 1;
            }

        }
    }
}

public String toString() {
    String s = year + "-" + (month > 9 ? month : "0" + month) + "-" + (day > 9 ? day : "0" + day) + " " + (hour > 9 ? hour : "0" + hour) + ":" + (minute > 9 ? minute : "0" + minute) + ":" + (second > 9 ? second : "0" + second);
    return s;
}
}
```

My test class is:

```
package date;

public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    CTime x = new CTime(23,59,59);
    CDateTime y = new CDateTime(2015,12,30,23,59,59);

    System.out.println(x);
    x.tick();
    System.out.println(x);


    System.out.println(y);
    y.tick();
    System.out.println(y);

}
}
```

How to add conditions :(
and thanks for the help.

Comment: I would consider changing your constructor to call your mutator methods on the parameters instead of setting the values directly. Then within your mutator methods, check the values being passed to see if they fall within the correct bounds. If they don't, then throw an appropriate Exception.

Comment: i am sorry , i didn't understand you

Answer (score 0):

In your set methods, you can check for the conditions using if.

Example :

```
public void setHour(int h) {
if(h >= 0 && h <= 23)   
    hour = h;
else
   System.out.println("Invalid hours");

}
```

Similarly you can do in the constructors as well. The correct way is to throw an exception, but since you can't use it, This should suffice.

Comment: This wouldn't prevent the user from specifying a constructor with invalid values.

Comment: I would advise against putting the same logic in multiple places, but instead calling `setHour(int h)` from within the constructor.

Comment: what do you mean with // throw an exception

Comment: Suppose if the condition fails, you will need to tell the user that this condition is violated. That you can do through an exception. Read about exceptions in Java.

Comment: @abdulaziz : Then leave it for now. Please accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: i can't do something i didn't study it , cuz me doctor will ask me about it , can i solve it with do while? or can you tell me another solution :(

Comment: @abdulaziz : Updated my answer. Please accept it if it works for you